# K8s port:8080 refused

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently trying to fix a k8s master+node setup (in 1 server).

1. When I do: `$ sudo kubectl cluster-info`
   Output

   ```
   To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
   The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
   ```
2. I have already done this:

   ```
   sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
   sudo chown $rtdev_user:$rtdev_user -g /home/rtdev_user/.kube/config
   ```

if I dont use "sudo" in kubectl cluster-info it outputs nothing.

```
$ kubectl config view:
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://x.x.x.x:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? How did you set up your k8s cluster ? What have you done so far ?
There's nothing we can do with that much infos.

Comment: Remove the dollar sign on the chown command, unless some "rtdev_user" bash variable is set.